# Holomorphic Function in $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question and would like someone to help me, 
I need to know: How to define a holomorphic function at $z= \infty$ ?

Answer (score 2):

We say that a function $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $z=\infty$ if the function $g(z):=f\left(\frac1z\right)$ is holomorphic (or at least has a removable singularity) at $z=0.$

Comment: But at $z=0$, $g$ is not defined

Comment: Good call. I completely misinterpreted what OP meant and thought he meant to ask for what the value at infinity of a holomorphic function is. This, of course, is impossible to do in general.

Comment: @WágnerBadilla what is meant in this case is that $g$ is holomorphic on $D(0,\delta)\setminus\{0\}$ for some small $\delta$ and extends to a holomorphic function Riemann's extension theorem style.

Comment: @Wagner: I have edited my answer to address that.